# Android Abstract Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, abstract-class

I'm trying to figure out a way to make an abstract layout.

I have a XML layout file, defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        style="@style/bigText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/QuestionArea"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/AnswerArea"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Title" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to create a family of classes, which all replace the QuestionArea and AnswerArea ViewGroups with their own custom Views. I've figured out how to get the ViewGroup, but I can't figure out how to take the other view and super-impose it with custom view I am making. Essentially, I want an abstract layout that I can pick and choose custom views to be inserted into placeholders.

Alternatively, I would appreciate any thoughts on what might be a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use ViewStubs and set the `inflatedId` by code.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html